# how to fix ImportError: No module named 'passlib

Tags: python, odoo-12

how to fix ImportError: No module named 'passlib

```
/Downloads/odoo-12.0$ ./odoo-bin

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/home/omprakash/Downloads/odoo-12.0/odoo/__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "/home/omprakash/Downloads/odoo-12.0/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/home/omprakash/Downloads/odoo-12.0/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "/home/omprakash/Downloads/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .config import config
  File "/home/omprakash/Downloads/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/config.py", line 18, in <module>
    from passlib.context import CryptContext

ImportError: No module named 'passlib'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to install `passlib`, using `pip`:

```
pip install passlib
```